# Trying to open a webdav excel spreadsheet via the protocol fails with "An unexpected error has occurred"

Tags: ms-office, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I installed recently Microsoft OneNote 2013 only (32 bit), but not Word and Excel 2013. I have Word and Excel 2010 installed though.

Now, when I try to open a webdav file using the protocol method (i.e. I type in IE 11: ms-excel:ofe|u|http://localhost/WebDav/test.xlsx) , I am prompted to open the file ("Some files can harm your computer blah blah blah"), then I click the OK button and I now get a message box with "An unexpected error has occurred". 
The process that shows the message is:
"C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office14\PROTOC~1.EXE" "ms-excel:ofe|u|http://localhost/WebDav/test.xlsx". I think the full name is the exe is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\protocolhandler.exe".

Any idea why this would return this obscure error message and not open the file? When I open the file via Excel 2010 -> File->Open and paste http://localhost/WebDav/test.xlsx it works fine.

I am using windows 7 64 bit ultimate.

Update: If I run the protocolhandler.exe from office 2013, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed this issue by setting this registry setting:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-excel\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\PROGRA~2\\MICROS~1\\Office15\\PROTOC~1.EXE \"%1\""
```